# Was Oliver Cromwell kidnapped by a monkey?

Tags: history

Seriously, I've have been informed that, as a baby, Oliver Cromwell was kidnapped by his grandfather's pet monkey.

At first glance this smells like a myth but does anyone know of any documentary evidence that suggests this might actually be true? Or at least the source of the myth?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The story or myth is found on various biographies of Oliver Cromwell notably

[Through Great Britain and Ireland With Cromwell](http://www.mainlesson.com/display.php?author=marshall&book=cromwell&story=childish)  by children's history author [Henrietta Elizabeth Marshall](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henrietta_Elizabeth_Marshall)

> There is a story told—I will not say
>   that it is a true one—of how, one day,
>   when Oliver was still a baby, he had
>   been taken to see his grandfather. He
>   lay asleep in his cradle, and his
>   nurse must have been careless, for he
>   was left all alone. As he lay there, a
>   monkey came lolloping into the room
>   and right up to the cradle. The monkey
>   thought that the baby would be a
>   lovely plaything, so he seized him and
>   ran away with him. Leaping, swinging,
>   clinging with hand and tail, he swung
>   himself and his prize up to the flat
>   lead roof of the house.
>
> Soon the baby was missed, and when it
>   was discovered that the monkey was
>   playing with him on the roof, the
>   whole household was thrown into a
>   state of confusion. Beds and blankets
>   were brought out and placed on the
>   ground, to catch the baby, in case the
>   monkey should drop or throw him down.
>   But the monkey was careful, and
>   presently he brought Oliver safely to
>   the ground again. So the baby was
>   saved to grow up to be a great man.

and again in this [chapter on the Civil War](http://www.hinchhouse.org.uk/civilwar/oliver.html)

> The man who became Lord Protector was
>   nephew to the Sir Oliver Cromwell who
>   owned Hinchingbrooke.It is said that
>   as a child he was taken by a pet
>   monkey and carried to the roof of
>   Hinchingbrooke. It is also said that
>   he met the young Charles at
>   Hinchingbrooke and gave him a bloody
>   nose.

Now I must quote straight from Ted Vallance's website -someone who has spent a lot of effort researching this -  and has a dedicated blogpost "[Oliver Cromwell and the Monkey](http://edwardvallance.wordpress.com/2009/07/28/oliver-cromwell-and-the-monkey/)"

> I wondered how old that particular
>   story was.
>
> Thomas Cromwell’s Oliver Cromwell and
>   His Times (1822) lists the story as
>   one of the many extravagant claims
>   inserted into hostile biographies of
>   his ancestor (referring here to Mark
>   Noble’s Memoirs of the Protectoral
>   House of Cromwell (1787)) Noble
>   claimed that he received this story –
>   and the other familiar one of the
>   young Oliver coming to blows with a
>   young Charles Stuart – from ‘the rev.
>   dr. Lort’s M.S.S.’ (Perhaps Michael
>   Lort, the Georgian antiquary?) who in
>   turn received this from ‘Mr. Audley’
>   (the non-juror Edward Audley).

The exact passage on [Google docs quotes the original incident](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=GIQpTMZo5FIC&pg=PA34&lpg=PA34&dq=oliver%20cromwell%20monkey&source=bl&ots=C7tiQdtwul&sig=n0BktQEmaJ-9JN8iqxnuy6CBWuA&hl=en&ei=TcluSv7UAdCgjAe3r9GfBQ&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=8#v=onepage&q=oliver%20cromwell%20monkey&f=false) thus

> His very infancy," says Noble, if we
>   believe what Mr. Audley, brother to
>   the famous civilian, says he had heard
>   some old men tell his grandfather, "
>   was marked with a peculiar accident,
>   that seemed to threaten the existence
>   of the future Protector: for his
>   grandfather, Sir Henry Cromwell,
>   having sent for him to Hinchinbrooke,
>   (near Huntingdon, the ancient family
>   seat) when an infant in arms, a monkey
>   took him from his cradle, and ran with
>   him upon the lead that covered the
>   roofing of the house. Alarmed at the
>   danger Oliver was in, the family
>   brought beds to catch him upon,
>   fearing the creature's dropping him
>   down; but the sagacious animal brought
>   the ' Fortune of England' down in
>   safety: so narrow an escape had he,
>   who was doomed to be the Conqueror and
>   Sovereign Magistrate of three mighty
>   nations, from the paws of a monkey."

**So in conclusion, there is an anecdote and an original reference point for the anecdote - but whether it was true or not is still debatable**

Furthermore, Andrew Barclay delves in some more and offers this comment on Ted Vallance's website to dig down the source of this tale

> Noble’s sources are actually rather
>   interesting. The implication is that
>   Lort was getting his information from
>   ‘mr. Edw. Audley’. There is certainly
>   another story told by Noble several
>   pages later on which is explicitly
>   said to derive from ‘The rev. dr.
>   Lort’s M.S.S. from papers communicated
>   by mr. Audley’ (1787 edn. i. p. 94n).
>   (Do those Lort MSS survive?)
>
> Moreover, on the previous page (i. p.
>   91n), Noble mentions ‘Mr. Edw. Audley,
>   a draper of Huntingdon, and brother of
>   the chancellor of York’, who had owned
>   the house in Huntingdon in which
>   Cromwell had been born. This is
>   clearly the same man.
>
> This provenance looks plausible. The
>   brother was presumably John Audley,
>   the chancellor of the archdiocese of
>   York in the early Hanoverian period.
>   My guess would be that John and Edward
>   Audley were the two sons of Edward
>   Audley who, according to the IGI (used
>   with all the usual caveats etc. etc.),
>   were baptised at Huntingdon in 1680
>   and 1682 respectively. Checking
>   whether the former is indeed the
>   future civil lawyer wouldn’t be too
>   difficult.
>
> Running the name Edward Audley through
>   the Cambridgeshire Archives online
>   catalogue
>   (http://www.cambridgeshire.gov.uk/leisure/archives/catalogue/)
>   throws up a number of documents,
>   including a will of 1757 of an Edward
>   Audley of Huntingdon, gent., in a
>   collection of documents relating to
>   Cromwell House, Huntingdon. An earlier
>   Edward Audley (the father?) seems to
>   have been one of the Huntingdon
>   aldermen in 1686. Further research
>   might establish whether there was an
>   Audley grandfather who, as Noble
>   claims, could have heard the story
>   about the monkey.
>
> It seems to me that the story might
>   well be a genuine example of
>   Huntingdon oral tradition. But Michael
>   Lort cannot have heard it much before
>   the middle of the eighteenth century
>   (he was only born in about 1725) and
>   at best Audley was reporting hearsay
>   at several removes. So we still can’t
>   assume that the story was actually
>   true.